# Webpack: How do I bundle multiple javascript files into a single output file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundling-and-minification

Suppose I have two files, **main.js** and **app.js**; how do I use Webpack to bundle both of them into one file: **bundle.js**?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

create one `entry.js` which is your webpack entry file and in this your `require` your additional files

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
   entry: './src/entry.js'
   ...
};
```

/src/entry.js

```
// new syntax
import './main.js';
import './app.js';

// or old syntax
require('./main.js');
require('./app.js');
```

if these two files depend on each other, it would be be beneficial to reflect this in your dependency tree and require `main.js` in your `app.js` and not in `entry.js` for example

Comment: I have a folder containing 15 third-party js files (either jQuery plugins or javascript libaries) that I would like to bundle into a single file.  None of these files "export" themselves to make themselves available to "import" from a single file - they are currently just referenced in script tags in an `index.html` file.  How can I bundle all these third party files into one file using webpack?

Comment: user1063287 you can try to use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader for this task

Comment: @c0l3 ...aaand it's no longer maintained.

Comment: as written in the repository. In most cases, you can replace the functionality by using raw-loader instead. For a example see script-loader readme

Answer (score 12):

You can pass an array of entries:

```js
module.exports = {
   entry: ['./main.js', './app.js'],
   ...
};
```

Also, you can pass them as a [CLI option](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#usage-without-configuration-file):

```
webpack ./main.js ./app.js --config=webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score 4):

As your question is about webpack, I assume you have installed webpack already
(e.g. with yarn: `yarn add --dev webpack webpack-cli`).

Now you have different options:

1. Specify all entry files inside `webpack.config.js`
2. Specify all entry files inside an extra entry file (e.g. `entry.js`)
3. Create the entry files array dynamically
4. Alternative: Bundling files with the TypeScript compiler
5. *(Using Plugins)*

### 1. Specify all entry files inside `webpack.config.js`

You can specify all wanted files inside the [`webpack.config.js`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/), e.g.:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./script1.js",
        "./script2.js"
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    // optimization: { minimize: false },
};
```

Then run webpack with e.g.:

```
yarn webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

### 2. Specify all entry files inside an extra entry file

Then you can import all your `.js` files into one "entry" file
(like `entry.js` or `index.js`), e.g.:

```
// entry.js: entry file for webpack
require('./script1.js');
require('./script2.js');
```

And then refer to this file inside the `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./entry.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    // optimization: { minimize: false },
};
```

Then run webpack with:

```
yarn webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

### 3. Create the entry files array dynamically

The entry property allows a function to [define the entries dynamically](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#dynamic-entry).

E.g. in an oversimplified way:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const sourceFolder = './src';

const createEntryFilesArray = function(){
    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ){
        fs.readdir( sourceFolder, (err, files) => {
            if( !err ){
                resolve(
                    files
                        .filter( file => file.endsWith('.js') )
                        .map( file => [ sourceFolder, file ].join('/') )
                );
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        })
    })
};

module.exports = {
    entry: createEntryFilesArray,
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

But you probably want to use more solid patterns (depending on you folder structure), e.g. including the use of [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob).

Furthermore, note that the file `webpack.config.js` is just a Javascript file,
so you could as well do whatever you want to create the entry files array dynamically.

E.g. in an oversimplified way:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const sourceFolder = './src';
const entryFilesArray = fs.readdirSync( sourceFolder )
    .filter( file => file.endsWith('.js') )
    .map( file => [ sourceFolder, file ].join('/') );

module.exports = {
    entry: entryFilesArray,
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

### 4. Alternative: Using the TypeScript compiler

Alternatively, if you don't specifically want to use webpack,
you also could use the TypeScript compiler,
e.g. in case you just want to bundle multiple `.js` and / or `.ts` files into one `.js` file,
especially if you are using TypeScript anyway.

This way you wouldn't need to install Webpack.
But note that this doesn't save space if you don't need to install Typescript anyway.
The package sizes are *(currently on my machine)*:

- `typescript`: 124 files, 67 MB
- `webpack`, `webpack-cli`: 3.347 files, 21 MB

#### Bundling files with the TypeScript compiler:

Install TypeScript, e.g.:

```
yarn add --dev typescript
```

Add a `tsconfig.json` file, e.g.:

```
{
    "files": [
        "./script1.js",
        "./script2.js"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",                           /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        "allowJs": true,                              /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
        "outFile": "./dist/bundle.js",                /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
        "outDir": "./dist",                           /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
//        "removeComments": false,                      /* Disable emitting comments. */
//        "esModuleInterop": true,                      /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
//        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,     /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
        "strict": true,                               /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    }
}
```

The target folder (e.g. `dist`) needs to exist, it will **not** be automatically created.

Start the TypeScript compiler with:

```
yarn run tsc --project tsconfig.json
```

### *5. Using Plugins*

*Apparently there are plugins that can bundle `.js` files in different ways,
but unfortunately I haven't tried any plugins yet. I hope to be able to add
an example here when I know more.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack-concat-plugin.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-concat-plugin#publicpath-stringboolean-default-webpacks-publicpath